# AmpScript/SSJS - Get text and translate it

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to use AmpScript/SSJS to get a text from an element and translate it to other languages?

Example: Before - Hello | After - Ciao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the AMPscript [HTTPGet()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/http/HTTPGet.html) function or the SSJS [Get()](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/http_server_side_javascript_functions/) function in conjunction with the Google Translate API where you make a GET request (using AMPscript or SSJS) to the following URL (including your API key in the URL parameter):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=YOUR_API_KEY&q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de
```

Refer to the [Google Translate API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/quickstart) for further information how to use their API.